# Rocket.Chat Ubuntu Snap Install LDAP Not Working

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, rocket.chat

I've just installed a Rocket.Chat server on Ubuntu 16.04.3 via Snap and have configured login via LDAP but it is not working.  Testing the connection indicates a successful test but login attempts and sync attempts fail.  Is it even necessary to Sync?  I would think that setting up pass-through LDAP authentication would bypass the need for any synchronization. That having been said, I've attempted the sync just to help narrow down the LDAP/Login issue.

Slightly Redacted Log snippet below:

```
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.251(-5) [34mLDAPHandler ➔ info Init LDAP login elorenz 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.255(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info Init setup 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.259(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info Connecting ldap://<<MyLDAPServerFQDN>> 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.262(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.debug connectionOptions { url: 'ldap://<<MyLDAPServerFQDN>>',   timeout: 60000,   connectTimeout: 1000,   idleTimeout: 1000,   reconnect: false } 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.270(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info LDAP connected 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.273(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Bind.info Binding UserDN <<MyLDAPServiceAccount>> 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.283(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.info Searching user elorenz 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.287(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.debug searchOptions { filter: '(&(objectclass=*)(sAMAccountName=elorenz))',   scope: 'sub',   sizeLimit: 1000,   paged: { pageSize: 250, pagePause: false } } 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.290(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.debug BaseDN cn=<<SomeOtherCN>>,cn=<<SomeCN>>,dn=stratford,dn=edu 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.298(-5) rocketchat_logger rocketchat_logger.js:375 [31mLDAP ➔ Search.error { [OperationsError: 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DB, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0 ]   lde_message: '000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DB, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0<br>\u0000',   lde_dn: null } 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.302(-5) rocketchat_logger rocketchat_logger.js:375 [31mLDAPHandler ➔ error { [OperationsError: 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DB, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0 ]   lde_message: '000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DB, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0<br>\u0000',   lde_dn: null } 
[34mI20171127-15:23:00.305(-5) [34mLDAPHandler ➔ info Fallback to default account system { username: 'elorenz' } 
[34mI20171127-15:23:01.298(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.info Idle 
[34mI20171127-15:23:01.300(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info Disconecting 
[34mI20171127-15:23:01.305(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.info Closed
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Hey @EricLavault, thanks for the quick reply.  I fixed the dn --> DC entry (fat finger on my part), Still have the issue. When I manually start a sync, I get a success message in the upper right corner of my browser but the logs indicate that the sync failed.

```
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.507(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info Init setup 
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.509(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info Connecting ldap://eqdcsu01.stratford.edu:389 
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.515(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info LDAP connected 
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.516(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Bind.info Binding UserDN svc_ldap@stratford.edu 
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.520(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.info Searching user * 
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.526(-5) rocketchat_logger rocketchat_logger.js:375 [31mLDAP ➔ Search.error { [NoSuchObjectError: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:  'DC=stratford,DC=edu' ]   lde_message: '0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:<br>\t\'DC=stratford,DC=edu\'<br>\u0000',   lde_dn: 'DC=stratford,DC=edu' } 
[34mI20171128-12:01:15.530(-5) Exception in callback of async function: NoSuchObjectError: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:  'DC=stratford,DC=edu'    at messageCallback (/snap/rocketchat-server/1188/programs/server/npm/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1419:45)   at Parser.onMessage (/snap/rocketchat-server/1188/programs/server/npm/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1089:14)   at emitOne (events.js:77:13)   at Parser.emit (events.js:169:7)   at Parser.write (/snap/rocketchat-server/1188/programs/server/npm/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/parser.js:111:8)   at Socket.onData (/snap/rocketchat-server/1188/programs/server/npm/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1076:22)   at emitOne (events.js:77:13)   at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)   at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)   at TCP.onread (net.js:540:20)  
[34mI20171128-12:01:16.525(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.info Idle 
[34mI20171128-12:01:16.527(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Connection.info Disconecting 
[34mI20171128-12:01:16.529(-5) [34mLDAP ➔ Search.info Closed
```

What's the best way to post the configuration info for you (and others)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your configuration ? The search base looks wrong : `BaseDN cn=<<SomeOtherCN>>,cn=<<SomeCN>>,dn=stratford,dn=edu`, there is what looks like a typo (_dn=_ instead of _dc=_) and the base might be too narrow to properly match users, `dc=stratford,dc=edu` should be ok.